# Convert textfield to be used in html class or id?

Tags: templating, filter, escaping

Does anyone know if it is possible to apply a Twig filter or use escaping to convert a Craft textfield into a html class/id safe string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Luke Holder's [Inflect plugin](https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-inflect). Which method to use would depend on how you want the resulting text to look. I'd use `{{ myTextField|slugify }}` to get a string that looks like this "this-is-my-class", since I only use lowercase and hyphenate class/id names.

Comment: Looks like I was a little to quick when hitting the accepted answer button :) The Inflect plugin doesn't seem to convert characters in the string to class/id safe characters. Any advice on this?

Comment: What characters isn't converted?

Comment: From my tests it seems like only spaces and casing are affected by the Inflect plugin. No other characters are converted, I have tested these so far: æøåüëäéóú